# Bluetooth stopped working correctly after possible update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

I been using bluetooth flawlessly on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS for the last 6 months, connecting mouse/keyboard/headphones simultaneously. But suddenly there was some kernel update I think because I had to update the kernel of my virtualbox which was a mess! and at the same time I started having regular issues with bluetooth which sometimes worked sometimes didnt.

Anyways tried a lot of things Googling and Im not sure if I messed up something but now my current bluetooth behaviour is as follows:

On booting/rebooting bluetooth does not work at all. Ubuntu thinks its on but I cant connect to or scan any device.

If I do just "sudo modprobe -r btusb; sudo modprobe btusb" (which I believe reinstalls the bluetooth driver or something) bluetooth starts working flawlessly, however after about 2 minutes it just stops again.

That's so weird. Obviously its working but why wont it just stay on??

Just in case it helps:

```
sudo dmesg | grep Blue
[    9.266691] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    9.266704] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.266710] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.266711] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.266714] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.285931] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    9.285932] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    9.285933] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    9.285945] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    9.285946] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    9.285946] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    9.285974] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    9.285982] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    9.285983] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    9.285984] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    9.285984] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    9.428155] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 103 week 50 2016
[   10.205097] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   10.205098] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   10.205100] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   12.659374] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   12.659377] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   12.659381] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   33.820193] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c52 tx timeout
[   57.756016] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0405 tx timeout
[  103.871505] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 103 week 50 2016
```

*--edit*

I tried some steps to remove and reinstall the bluetooth package but still the problem persists. For some reason instead of working for 2 minutes my bluetooth now just works about 15 seconds after restarting the driver.
My syslog shows this just after it happened.

```
tail syslog
Jan 28 13:43:51 pierre-Galago-Pro system76-daemon[1255]: 2018-01-28 13:43:51,967  INFO  {'hci0': True, 'phy0': True} != {'phy0': True}
Jan 28 13:43:51 pierre-Galago-Pro system76-daemon[1255]: 2018-01-28 13:43:51,970  INFO  airplane_mode: False
Jan 28 13:44:04 pierre-Galago-Pro bluetoothd[1306]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_57_D3_98_0B_83_19/fd1: fd(36) ready
Jan 28 13:44:04 pierre-Galago-Pro rtkit-daemon[3655]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jan 28 13:44:04 pierre-Galago-Pro rtkit-daemon[3655]: Successfully made thread 10504 of process 5763 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jan 28 13:44:04 pierre-Galago-Pro rtkit-daemon[3655]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jan 28 13:44:04 pierre-Galago-Pro kernel: [  317.466103] input: 57:D3:98:0B:83:19 as /devices/virtual/input/input27
Jan 28 13:44:23 pierre-Galago-Pro bluetoothd[1306]: Suspend: Connection timed out (110)
Jan 28 13:44:25 pierre-Galago-Pro bluetoothd[1306]: Abort: Connection timed out (110)
Jan 28 13:44:25 pierre-Galago-Pro acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 22
```

it seems bluetoothd is a daemon of the package named bluez and I can see that the bluez package has just been updated quite recently for Ubuntu 16.04 ( https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez ) maybe I might need to downgrade to the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

Well wonderfully it appears I might have solved this for now in the most unprobable way.

I have tried so many things, installing/reinstalling various packages, there was a system update that I installed, rebooted so many times, nothing fixed it until I read this page from the System76 support: http://support.system76.com/articles/bluetooth/

It starts by suggesting to toggle Airplane mode to see if it fixes your issue. Well it totally did!